# Unknown type name for struct in header file

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I have a header file where I would like to define a few default colors.

```c
typedef struct _color {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char a;
} color;

/* Default colors */

// initializes to (0, 0, 0, 0)
color TRANSPARENT;

color color_black;
color_black.a = 255;

color color_red;
color_red.r = 255;
color_red.a = 255;

color GREEN;
GREEN.g = 255;
GREEN.a = 255;
```

When I compile with `clang -I. -c -o image.o image.c`, I get the following errors:

```
In file included from image.c:5:
./image.h:25:1: error: unknown type name 'color_black'
color_black.a = 255;
^
./image.h:25:12: error: expected identifier or '('
color_black.a = 255;
           ^
./image.h:28:1: error: unknown type name 'color_red'
color_red.r = 255;
^
./image.h:28:10: error: expected identifier or '('
color_red.r = 255;
...
```

This continues for all of the colors I have defined.

I'm not sure why it thinks the variables should be type names, especially when I have already declared them. I have tried using `extern` and changing the variable names' style to ALL CAPS.

Comment: `color_black.a = 255;` You can't write statement at global scope, all such code must go inside a function. If you just want to initialize the variables, write `color color_black = { 0, 0, 0, 255 };` instead.

Comment: btw your struct definition is a c-ism. In C++ you can write `struct color { ... };`

Comment: Defining global variables in header files is not a good idea.

Comment: oh, this is C, not C++

Comment: Please remember that C and C++ are two different languages. Do you need an answer for both?

Answer (score 2):

You are running code outside of a function.

```c
printf("a");
```

doesnt compile either, so why should assignment expressions?

instead do

```c
color color_black = {0,0,0,255};
```